# using aws-sdk to send out OTP verification sms on phone_number

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk

I have created a userpool in aws for otp verification with phone_numbers.

below is the code snippet that is sending out OTP message.

```
import { CognitoIdentityServiceProvider } from "aws-sdk";

const cognito = new CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({
  region: "ca-central-1",
});

const userPoolId = "ca-central-xxx";
const appClientId = "xxx";

export async function sendOTP(phoneNumber: string, password: string) {
  const params = {
    ClientId: appClientId,
    Username: phoneNumber,
    Password: password,
    UserAttributes: [
      {
        Name: "phone_number",
        Value: phoneNumber,
      },
    ],
  };

  return cognito.signUp(params).promise();
}
```

when I call the function I get this in the response.

```
{
  UserConfirmed: false,
  CodeDeliveryDetails: {
    Destination: '+********2004',
    DeliveryMedium: 'SMS',
    AttributeName: 'phone_number'
  },
  UserSub: '8cdd9528-a001-70fc-f556-xxxx'
}
```

to me it looks like I was able to send out otp message successfully but I did not get any verification code on my phone_number.
I tried to debug this, created and deleted multiple user_pools with different IAM roles but nothing worked.

I am sure that the aws failed to send out the OTP because this is what is shown in the console.
[image]

In the image above you can see that some of the OTP verification message where sent successfully but this happened initially. later it stoped working.

I need help to debug this, what could be the possible reasons?

NOTE: I am in sandbox mode not in production and YES I am sending out OTP's on verified phone_numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this.
I was using the old method of sending out OTP's. AWS has update their sdk and I used `@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider` instead and it worked.